# bundler not running before whenever in cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, whenever, whenever-capistrano

I am trying to run cap depoly and i get the following error that says

```
  command finished in 881ms
  * 2013-01-24 12:50:53 executing `whenever:update_crontab'
  * executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/cf/releases/20130124115051 && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab cf --set environment=production --roles db"
    servers: ["208.68.37.172"]
    [208.68.37.172] executing command
 ** [out :: 208.68.37.172] Could not find acts-as-taggable-on-2.3.3 in any of the sources
 ** [out :: 208.68.37.172] 
 ** [out :: 208.68.37.172] Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
 ** [out :: 208.68.37.172] 
    command finished in 1957ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/cf/releases/20130124115051; true"
    servers: ["208.68.37.172"]
    [208.68.37.172] executing command
    command finished in 935ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/cf/releases/20130124115051 && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab cf --set environment=production --roles db'" on 208.68.37.172
```

I later realized that bundler is not running before whenever command and this happened after upgrading my rails app to the latest version of rails. 3.2.11. any help thanks.

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "whenever/capistrano"

server "208.68.37.172", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "xx"
set :user, "deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:ramza1/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"


  after "deploy:update_code" do
    run "mkdir -p #{release_path}/ckeditor_assets"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/ckeditor_assets #{release_path}/public/ckeditor_assets"
  end

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Comment: What version the whenever `gem` are you running?. Also I can see on you deploy the error `Could not find acts-as-taggable-on-2.3.3 in any of the sources`

Comment: i am using version whenever (0.8.2)

Comment: i am using bundler/capistrano and its not running bundle install before anyother thing

Comment: see that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511706/whenever-gem-fails-to-run-bundle-exec-correctly-in-capistrano/14852487#14852487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problems are both:

The first, On your `deploy.rb` recipe add on **the top** of this file the next:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

The second I think that you must install from your gem file:

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
```

The third problem is whenever version, on version `whenever 0.8.2` fail with deploy. Uninstall version 0.8.2 and install for example `whenever (0.7.3)`

Uninstall `acts-as-taggable-on-2.3.3` and check if without that gem the deploy is working.

Also I use `rbenv` and I have this in my bash_profile before any other $PATH declarations to make sure it grabs those executables first:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Remove from the top the `set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"` and add this code after `set :branch, "master"`

**Try these steps to see if it works**

Regards!

Comment: I think the third is the problem cos i have already reinitialized the first and second

Comment: Ok, please try the deploy with version `whenever (0.7.3)`

Comment: i just did and i am having the same thing

Comment: and if i try installing the gem manually on the server, i get another gem error which is making it look like i have to install all the gems manually on the server

Comment: any idea on how i can make bundler run before the whenever command fron d deploy script

Comment: have you tried uninstall `acts-as-taggable-on-2.3.3` and deploy without this gem? I have added more possible fix to your problem on my response!

Comment: yes. i will get another missing gem error of another gem. i thing the problem is than capistrano is not running bundle install first

Comment: Remove from the top the `set :whenever_command`, `"bundle exec whenever"` and add this code after `set :branch, "master"`

Comment: it looks like whenever requires all my gems to be installed on the ruby version itself cos if i remove whenever from my cap deploy it works but if i add it keep getting the gem errors

Comment: i had to uninstall the latest whenever form my system and it works now

Comment: I had the same problem with the last whenever version. Glad to hear that the problem has been solved :D. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it seems acts-as-taggable-on is missing

To install acts-as-taggable-on

`gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'` on your **Gemfile**

or go there to find specific version of this gem
https://rubygems.org/gems/acts-as-taggable-on

Comment: it on my gem file and i am trying to deploy with capistrano and if i try installing the gem one after the other i will end up getting a new gem error. the problem is bundler is not running before the whenever task

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Type the following from terminal

```
 crontab -e
```

This opens the crontab for editing.

Now you will see two lines as below:

```
PATH=/<path to bundle>/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems
```

AND

```
PATH=/<path to bundle>/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems
```

Comment out both lines beginning with PATH.

Do the above step whenever you run `bundle exec whenever` command. And it works.

Comment: i just checked and i cant see any of those two lines. i am using rbenv not rvm